# OMNeT++ sumo and veins_inet

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have to create two vehicle to communicate as my first step. I have install veins_inet but how to communicate them in OMNeT++ and then represent them in SUMO.

Comment: Have you tried the example simulation that comes with this software? Which aspect is giving you trouble?

Comment: I'am beginner in omnetpp and i have problems could i don't find tutorial so i have to make multiple wirless host to use them as cars and a fixed object that are the route object like traffic lights and speed limitation that would send messages if the car have a speed bigger than the announced and to send messages between cars so could i know if i. Need something other veins_inet and how to represenet them on sumo do you have any site so i can refer on it thank you plus i found some errors i have try to run just the veins_inet

Comment: I've tried my best to understand your reply. I could not understand it. If you are looking for a discussion forum, StackOverflow is not the right place (it is built to get a specific answer to a particular question). Google groups or similar lists are much better for overall discussions.